# mathclap: undefined control sequence

Tags: math-mode, errors, align

In my preamble I have loaded the `amsmath` and `geometry` package and many others that I read are useful when using `\mathclap`. This is my preamble

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,abstracton]{scrartcl}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}               %Zeichencodierung Text
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                     %Schriftsatz Dokument


%%Language settings
\usepackage[english]{babel}                  %ngerman for German
\usepackage{csquotes}                        %[babel,quotes=english]
\usepackage{caption}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}}
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}   % only works when not using babel


%%Math, astro, chemical packages and options
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts,amsbsy,latexsym}
\usepackage{wasysym}                        %astronomical symbols
%\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}             %Chemie-Package
\providecommand{\e}[1]{\ensuremath{\times 10^{#1}}}

%\usepackage{dsfont}
%\usepackage{enumerate,url}


%%Paper adjustments
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}                        %if problems with importing .eps graphics
%\usepackage{a4wide}                         %obsolete and replaced by geometry
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom=3.1cm]{geometry}  %also with command \geometry{options}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
%\usepackage{subfigure}                      %obsolete
\usepackage{subcaption}                      %cannot be used with subfigure
%\usepackage{subfig}
%\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{textcomp, gensymb}               %textcomp before gensymb gets rid of the warnings "not defining \micro and \perthousand
\usepackage{soul}                            %for customised working with the text 
\usepackage{array}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}                  %sets the section number depth
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}                     %sets the ToC depth
%\usepackage{verbatim}                       %for multiline comments using\begin or \end
\usepackage{xcolor}                          %colour e.g. parts of equations

%% Control the fonts and formatting used in the table of contents.
%\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

%% Aesthetic spacing redefined
%\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{}
%\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}                  %kein Einrücken von neuen Abschnitten
\usepackage{afterpage}                       %to avoid space before landscape-environment
```

I still get errors for

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
...&\stackrel{\mathclap}{\rightarrow}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

First I had only "align" instead of "aligned". Those undefined control sequences vanished, but are replaced by undefined control sequences for this `\mathclap` (which was already before a non recognised command...I'm wondering why). Unfortunately, my document has too many errors to be displayed with the recent necessary changes that were necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to accomplish with `\stackrel{\mathclap}{\rightarrow}`; you probably want something like `\xrightarrow{f}` to have a label over an (extensible) arrow.

Answer (score 12):

The macro `\mathclap` is defined in package `mathtools`:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

The macro takes an optional argument for the math style and a mandatory argument for the math stuff, which is put in a zero-width box and centered there.
Therefore,

```
\stackrel{\mathclap}{\rightarrow}
```

does not make sense, since the mandatory argument for `\mathclap` is missing.